# Azure Web App - Why does it only let you select Linux as an operating system when you select Runtime stack as Node.js?

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, linux, azure

Why does Azure only let you select Linux as an operating system when you want to use Node.js as the Runtime stack and why does it matter?  Ideally, I want to use Azure for my ios app that I'm currently programming in Xcode on my MacBook pro.

[image]

Comment: From [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/845687/azure-app-service-on-linux-or-windows) on Servier Fault, looks like there were some reported issues with node on windows. Not sure if that is why you're required to use linux after it came out of preview.

Comment: Did some testing, seems it depends on node version with no clear pattern. Some versions support both Linux and Windows, some only one or some only the other. For example, node 10.0 supports only Windows while 10.6 supports both.

Comment: Unix/Linux questions should be programming related. I suggest to visit https://unix.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 0):

In Azure web app, Runtime stack with

Node 10.14,

Node 10.6,

Node 10.0,

Node 8.11,

Node 8.10,

Node 8.9,

Node 8.5,

Node 8.4,

Node 8.1,

Node 7.10,

Node 6.12,

Node 6.9,

Node 6.5,

Node 4.8

support Windows operation system.

Not sure why the other versions doesn't support windows os, if you want to know the details, you can raise a support ticket on Azure portal by following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request.